# Can we extend the linear independence of some vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

If we have a set of linearly indepent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if we add a new component in the same position to each vector, is that new set linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?

I am not sure if I was clear enough with the question. For instance, we know that the vectors $(1,0,2)$ and $(2,3,6)$ are linearly indepent in $\mathbb{R}^3$. If we add a new component in both vectors between the first one and the second one, we get the vectors $(1,a,0,2)$ and $(2,b,3,6)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. These vectors are still linearly independent, since no one of them is multiple of the other.

I want to know if that property always holds and why.

Comment: The dual map $\Bbb{R}^{n++}\to\Bbb{R}^n$, the well defined linear map that removes the component  is onto but not one-to-one since it has a one dimensional nullspace. From the pov of this map, the image of linearly dependent vectors must linearly dependent. Thus the contrapositve is logically equivalent: linearly independent vectors must have had linearly independent preimages.

Comment: @NinadMunshi What do you mean with pov?

Comment: Pov means point of view

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thanks!! I got it.